# GULP. Установка. Ошибка. HELP!

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, scss, gulp4

Уважаемые программисты. 4 день мучаюсь с Gulp проект закончен и все файлы проверенны. Но галп упорно отказывается работать. Переустановил его, node.js, перенес проект в другую папку, удалял и устанавливал все с 0. Помогите, подскажите в чем моя ошибка и что нужно сделать. Либо на крайней случай подскажите как совместить все файлы scss/html/js/img. в один готовый проект и запустить его хотя бы на локалке для проверки работоспособности скриптов

Что делал по пунктам.

1. установил node.js
2. npm install --global gulp-cli
3. npm init
4. npm install --save-dev gulp
5. все остальное снизу

`
$ node --version
v16.15.1
$ npm --version
8.11.0
$ npx --version
8.11.0

$ npm install --save-dev gulp

up to date, audited 1485 packages in 10s

57 vulnerabilities (1 low, 33 moderate, 23 high)

$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

$ gulp
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\123\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js from C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\123\gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\123\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object. (C:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\123\gulpfile.js:14:18)
at async Promise.all (index 0) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
`

После npm audit fix --force
Ошибок становиться еще больше
74 vulnerabilities (35 moderate, 20 high, 19 critical)
**Подскажите как полностью очистить систему, какими командами можно удалить все файлы и пакеты и установить с нуля чистый галп, без лишних пакетов**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии 8.0.0, `gulp-imagemin` использует только ESM и не поддерживает CommonJS. Чтобы этой ошибки не возникало, установите `gulp-imagemin@7.1.0` - это последняя версия с поддержкой CommonJS.

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-imagemin@7.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

@Neverm1ndo спасибо за ответ, но там все равно 74 ошибки совместимости. В итоге удалил, все почистил и аккуратно поставил с учётом ошибок и версий